# Can't write non current user objects by PFUser currentuser

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I would like write a `PFUser` object by the `currentUser`, i've added the `ACL` based on the Parse developer guide, but i still get an error:

```
 'User cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp'
```

_ My code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:self.bBo];
    PFObject *friendData = [query getFirstObject];

    PFUser *user = (PFUser *)friendData;

    PFACL *userACL = [PFACL ACL];

    user.ACL = userACL;

    [userACL setWriteAccess:YES forUser:[PFUser currentUser]];

    PFRelation *friendRelation = [user relationforKey:@"array"];
    [friendRelation addObject:[PFUser currentUser]];

    [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

I think i did everything correct, so i can't figure out what can be the problem. So if you made earlier something like this or know where is the problem, i would really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For security reasons, Parse won't allow you to save any changes to a user that is not currently logged in.

If you want to be able to make and save changes to `user`, you need to use `Cloud Code` and the `Master Key` to get around this roadblock.

I have had multiple problems like this before, and every time I've been forced to use a workaround via `Cloud Code`.

Here's an example of a workaround I did for creating a friends relationship between two users:

```
[PFCloud callFunction:@"editUser" withParameters:@{@"userId": user.objectId}];
```

The above code statement is in xcode, and executes the function I have added to my `Cloud Code` file.

Then, here's what my `Cloud Code` file looks like:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('editUser', function(request, response) {
    var userId = request.params.userId;

    var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
        user = new User({ objectId: userId });

    var currentUser = request.user;

    var relation = user.relation("friendsRelation");
    relation.add(currentUser);

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    user.save().then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error)
    });
});
```

The above code uses the `Master Key` to save changes to both the currently logged in user, and to the user who's objectId was passed into this function.

Code details:

```
var relation
```

This is just a variable I'm creating to hold what the following fucntion returns:

```
user.relation("friendsRelation");
```

In the above function, `"friendsRelation"` is the name of my PFRelation key in Parse.

Now that we have a valid relation object contain in our variable called `relation`, we execute this function with an argument of our `currentUser` object.

After that, all that's left is saving everything. I don't program with javascript, but I was still able to come up with the above solution by looking at the `Parse Cloud Code` docs, and searching around on their support forums.

If you take my template from above, and make some small changes, then you should be able to easily accomplish what you need. You just have to jump through these extra hoops because the `Parse SDK` doesn't want a situation where someone can login and somehow make changes to another user's account, whether by their own fault or a developer's mistake.

EDIT:

Here is the code to add the relationship for the current user:

```
PFRelation *friendsRelation = [[PFUser currentUser]relationforKey:@"friendsRelation"];

    PFUser *user = [self.parseUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [friendsRelation addObject:user];
    [currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

And then you can call the Cloud Code method right after:

```
    [PFCloud callFunction:@"editUser" withParameters:@{
                                                       @"userId": user.objectId
                                                       }];
```

Comment: Is it a legal solution? I mean, Apple will accept it? Because they won't be able to review the code, that runs in the CloudCode.

Comment: It works perfectly, it sets the relation only for the not current user. However i would like to try the other version, where it sets the relation for both users. Possibly do you have any idea why doesn't works it? I didn't edited it.

Comment: Yes this is a legal solution. Apple has no way of knowing anyways, and the master key solution has been recommended by Parse admins on their support forums.

Comment: The code that I posted above sets the relation for both users. If you click on their relation field in Parse, it should show the other person.

Comment: I did, but it sets only the current user for the other user.

Comment: @vv88 If you want the other user added to the current user's `friendsRelation` you can do that yourself in your client code, there's no restriction on saving the current user.

Comment: @TimothyWalters Thanks you for the tip, i will do that if i can't do the CloudCode version, but it would be nicer to save them in the same file.

Comment: @user3344977 if you don't mind, I could edit your question to show how to save both currentUser->other and other->currentUser, unless you want to do it yourself.

Comment: @TimothyWalters sorry, i've almost forget.. you can answer it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587976/define-mutual-relation-between-two-user-with-parse-javascript

Comment: My answer has been updated. You can now add the friend relationship for both the currently logged in user and for the other user via cloud code.