# Define mutual relation between two user with Parse JavaScript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, parse-platform

I would like to set a simple relation between the current user and another user (userB). I can create the `sampleRelation`, and current user shown up at userB's `sampleRelation` column in the data browser, but current user's relation list is blank, even though it should display userB's name. Javascript is totally unknown for me, i have to use it because the CloudCode, originally i'm using the iOS SDK where i call this CloudCode function like this:

```
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (object) {
PFUser *user = (PFUser *)object;          
[PFCloud callFunction:@"editUser" withParameters:@{@"userId": user.objectId}]; }];
```

and here is the JavaScript implementation:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('editUser', function(request, response) {
               var userId = request.params.userId;

               var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
               user = new User({ objectId: userId });

               var currentUser = request.user;

               var relation = user.relation("sampleRelation");
               relation.add(currentUser);

               currentUser.save();

               Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
               user.save().then(function(user) {
                                response.success(user);
                                }, function(error) {
                                response.error(error)
                                });
               });
```

I'm sure that somehow i need to save the relation for the current user, therefore i added the `currentUser.save();` line, but nothing changed. I can't figure out that i missed something to implement or the existing code hides the bug.

My try based on Timothy's answer.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('editUser', function(request, response) {
               var userId = request.params.userId;

               var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
               user = new User({ objectId: userId });

               var currentUser = request.user;

               var relation = user.relation("sampleRelation");

               relation.add(currentUser);

               Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
               var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
               userQuery.get(request.params.userId)
               .then(function (user) {
                     var relation = user.relation("sampleRelation");
                     relation.add(request.user);
                     // chain the promise
                     return user.save();
                     ).then(function (user) {
                            response.success(user);
                            }, function (error) {
                            response.error(error);
                            });
```

And here is the error that i got:

```
Update failed with Could not load triggers.  The error was Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in main.js:28
```

Second update

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.get(request.params.userId)
.then(function (user) {
      var relation = user.relation("sampleRelation");
      relation.add(request.user);
      // chain the promise
      return user.save();
      }).then(function (user) {
              response.success(user);
              }, function (error) {
              response.error(error);
              });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't changing the `currentUser` so calling `currentUser.save()` will not do anything.

Also when getting an existing user you should do the following:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('editUser', function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    userQuery.get(request.params.userId)
    .then(function (user) {
        var relation = user.relation("sampleRelation");
        relation.add(request.user);
        // chain the promise
        return user.save();
    }).then(function (user) {
        var currentUser = request.user;
        var relation = currentUser.relation("sampleRelation");
        relation.add(user);
        // chain the new promise
        return currentUser.save();
    }).then(function () {
        response.success();
    }, function (error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: It's possible that i did something wrong, but i got an error. I've updated my question with my try that based on your answer.

Comment: I realised in mine I missed a `}` after the `return user.save();` line. Also in your updated code, you can remove everything before the call to `useMasterKey()`.

Comment: I got this with the updated code,  `Update failed with Could not load triggers.  The error was ReferenceError: request is not defined at main.js:3:15` Possibly do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Umm, did you leave the `Parse.Cloud.define()` line there? Maybe refresh your updated code in the question.

Comment: No, i've deleted it. I also updated my question, it's the all code from my main.js.

Comment: OK, you still need to wrap that in the `define()` function, I'll update my code to be a complete example.

Comment: Almost working, i can set `currentUser` for `userB`'s `sampleRelation`, but can't set `userB` for `currentUser`.

Comment: Updated to handle that too.

Comment: Works fine. Thank you very much. Just one more question, I also make a query to get `user.objectId` (userB's username) before i call the CloudCode method. So i see 2 other query in your JavaScript code (it's totally possible that I'm wrong, because my js knowledge is zero), it's not possible that one of them is not needed?

Comment: Sorry, somehow i can't award the bounties in 20 hours, but i will do it.

Comment: I did all of this...It says "parent not defined"