# How do I save a relationship between currentUser and another ParseUser?

Tags: android, parse-platform

[Can't write non current user objects by PFUser currentuser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580413/cant-write-non-current-user-objects-by-pfuser-currentuser)

Referencing the above article, there's countless (literally loads) of iOS examples of how to create a many-many relationship between ParseUsers, and yet not a single one written in Android, there's zero documentation on it whatsoever.

If someone could explain how to do this, that'd be great thank you.

> I've tried:

```
        ParseUser friend = getParseUser(username); // I search for a friend here
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); // this is me, I have rights to write to me
    try {
        ParseRelation<ParseUser> relation = user.getRelation("friends");
        relation.add(friend);

        // if I use user.save(); I get no error back obviously - but it does nothing
        // if I use user.saveEventually() I get a neverending loop of ParseErrors
        // claiming I can't save to that object - Yes I'm logged in.

        user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        //I report errors further on, but the rest is unreachable as this fails.
```

And lots of varients of that same code. I don't want to use pointers (Parse DB thing) I want to use their relational model, but this code comes back saying **unable to encode an association with an unsaved ParseObject**

Again, there's lots of documentation for iOS AND for getting `ParseObjects` or yourself (`ParseUser.getCurrentUser()`) but there's nothing that shows how you get a ParseUser (not yourself) then create a relationship with them and yourself. Nowhere.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you have gone through [this](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pointers)?

Comment: I'm certain. If I have missed something, I'm open to suggestions but I've covered their documentation on Android thoroughly. Nowhere does it give an example of how you retrieve another user object (not myself) then create a relationship with that user. Nowhere.

Thank you for the reply though, but yes, everyone keeps pointing me to the same 3 paragraphs that very loosely cover the ParseUser object and relationships with it.