# Save changes to a user that is not currently logged in

Tags: javascript, swift, parse-platform

In my `_User` class I have a column named `check`. The initial value of the column for `someUser`(some other saved user) is `true` and as a `currentUser`(currently logged in user) I want to be able to change that value to `false`.

Unfortunately for security reasons, Parse won't allow me to save any changes to a user that is not currently logged in, and I get an error: `User cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp`. I already tried adding `ACL` to Public `read and write`, but It didn't work.
I know I need to use `Cloud Code` and the `Master Key` to get it sorted out.
There is this post: [Can't write non current user objects by PFUser currentuser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580413/cant-write-non-current-user-objects-by-pfuser-currentuser), but I can't figure out the way to adapt it.

Comment: The question is how to use Master key in Cloud Code?

Comment: Yes. I want to give a currentUser Write access  in the _User class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test_func", function (request, response) {

var user  = request.user;
user.increment("blabla", value); //do user stuff
user.save(); // You don't need masterkey to edit your own user object

// Get authentication to edit other user objects
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

// query or get another user
var user2 = ...
user2.increment("blabla", value); // do user2 stuff
user2.save();

// Finish cloud func
response.success("yeeey");
}
```

If you don't useMasterKey Parse will give error while saving user2

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("update_user", function(request, response) {
 var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
 query.equalTo("objectId", request.params.objectId)
 // Queries user to be updated
 query.first({
  success: function(user) {
   user.set("check", request.params.check);

   // Updates user (using MasterKey to get permission to update non logged in users)
   user.save(null, { useMasterKey: true }).then(function() {
    response.success();
   }, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
   });
   
  }, error: function(error) {
   response.error(error);
  }
 });
});
```

And call the "update_user" function (e.g.: in Objective-C):

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"objectId" : user.objectId,
                            @"check" : @"true"};

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"update_user" withParameters:params block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error.userInfo[@"error"]);
    }];
```