# Using Parse User's Master Key to save relations not working

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am attempting to link a `School` class with a list of users (a `School` can have many `User`s, and a `User` belongs to a `School`). Per several suggestions, I am using Parse's Cloud Code and Master key to accomplish this.

My issue is that, instead of passing a string parameter or another `User`, I am linking a `School` object to the user.

Here is my Cloud Code, which is causing an error when ran and no changes made to Parse's backend:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('addNewSchoolRelation', function(request, response) {
    var userId = request.params.userId,
        associatedSchoolObject = request.params.associatedSchoolObject; 

    var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
        user = new User({ objectId: userId });

    var relation = user.relation("schoolRelation");
    relation.set(associatedSchoolObject);


    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    user.save().then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error)
    });
});
```

And inside my app, this is how I call it:

```
PFQuery *schoolQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"School"];
    [schoolQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:@"FgpHfOGIdC"]; //this is the test one
    [schoolQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
        } else {

            PFObject *school = [objects firstObject];

            [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"addNewSchoolRelation" withParameters:

             @{@"userId": @"BHqvZ6PrLl", //testing for now
               @"associatedSchoolObject": school,

               } //sets that user's newChats

                                        block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                                            if (error){
                                                NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
                                            } else {
                                                NSLog(@"Saved on remote user");
                                            }
                                        }];

        }
    }];
```

I'm pretty sure culprit is in my Javascript code - am I passing the parameter incorrectly? I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly and any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but associatedSchoolObject is a JSON dictionary not Parse.Object.extend so you can't use it to make a relation.

Comment: Ah got it. I have seen relations formed when making the connection to another user per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580413/cant-write-non-current-user-objects-by-pfuser-currentuser and thought it may work with other objects as well.